# Obtaining a public IP or domain name in a Knative+MiniKube setup

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns, knative, knative-serving

I am attempting to use [knative](https://knative.dev) to self-host a simple FaaS platform from an on-premises Linux server.  I have installed [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) successfully, and installed/configured knative using the [knative operator](https://knative.dev/docs/install/operator/knative-with-operators/).

Following the default selection in the linked guide, I have set up **kourier** as the networking layer and selected **Magic DNS** (sslip.io) setup.  After running `minikube tunnel`, I can successfully serve demo apps like [helloworld-python](https://github.com/knative/docs/tree/main/code-samples/serving/hello-world/helloworld-python).

However, my "External IP" according to KNative is a private-ip:

```bash
kubectl --namespace knative-serving get service kourier

NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
kourier   LoadBalancer   10.100.195.53   10.100.195.53   80:31140/TCP,443:31175/TCP   15h
```

(Note the IP starts with `10.`, this IP is not external to the machine.)

As such, the apps return sslip.io addresses containing this private IP: `http://helloworld-python.default.10.100.195.53.sslip.io`. As a result, I can query this service (e.g. via `curl`) just fine from the host server, but I can't access the service from any other machine.  Likewise, if I attempt to configure any "Eventing" services, KNative produces webhooks with a private IP address, which obviously don't work since external services like GitHub don't resolve them.

So, *why does Knative* return a private IP in this setting?  The KNative installation doesn't seem to give any indication that this will be the case, suggesting that

```
kubectl --namespace knative-serving get service kourier
```

might return a CNAME or an IP address and that we should "note this for DNS configuration later" (except if using Magic DNS).  Should it be returning a private IP?

- If so, what is the procedure for exposing services? Do I need to run some additional configuration to expose a public IP?
- If not, is some additional per-configuration needed so that it uses the machine's public IP?  (or at least an IP I can bind my own reverse proxy to?)
- Is *Kourier* designed to only do private IPs?  (The docs are pretty terse about why one should chose *kourier* vs *istio* or *contour* for networking, merely saying that *istio* is the default but new users should chose *kourier* if they are unsure??)

As a side-note/ background context, my server has a fixed IP address, I use [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) (in container on the same docker network as minikube) to provide https domain names to services.  Also, outside of knative, if I just follow standard [minikube guide](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) to make a service as NodePort or LoadBalancer, I can easily take the port that `kubectl get svc` shows, and expose the service in caddy by pointing to said port on the minikube container, something like this in the Caddyfile:

```
minikube.app.mydomain.com {
  reverse_proxy minikube:32637 {
    header_up Host {host}
  } 
}
```

This is just to confirm that in vanilla minikube I have no trouble with ingress configuration.  KNative clearly has this extra layer of networking by which it's generating URLs for applications though and that has be flummoxed.  I can't just replace the `minikube:32637 with the private IP addresses KNative returns)

Answer (score 1):

Knative uses the HTTP `Host` header to share a single IP address across many services (sorta like what you're doing with caddy...).

If you want to use caddy to route these requests, you'll need to rewrite the `Host` header using [the `header_up` directive](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy#headers). You may be able to use the replacement form and/or change the Knative domain prefix to make this easier.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I see KNative mapping the IP address across different services with subdomains, that makes total sense.  The difficulty I have is that it has chosen to map a Private IP address,  10.100.195.53, so these services are not accessible.  I don't understand the mechanism by which I expose that. In particular, I can't even tell if I am supposed to roll with that private IP by redirecting external requests to it, or alter configuration somehow to use a public IP.  

Caddy passes through the headers as you know.  I can add `header_up {host}` to my ex above but does not address the issue.

Comment: The "external ip" detected by Knative is simply using the `minikube tunnel` IP address.

Comment: Try something like ```minikube.app.mydomain.com {
  reverse_proxy 10.100.195.53:80 {
    header_up Host helloworld-python.default.10.100.195.53.sslip.io
  } 
}```

Comment: oh hmm I see what you mean now about header_up, clever!  It still doesn't like that though.  Good to know what is responsible for selecting the external IP, perhaps I need to look at configuring minikube tunnel instead of adjusting something in caddy or knative(?)